# Is there any reason why i get a DTD error every single time?

Tags: xml, dtd

im doing my homework in XML, just started out with DTD, every single time i try to validate the dtd document i get the same error every single time. "

> FATALERROR at line 1, column2: excpected comment or CDATA section".

i really dont know why. the xml is fine, validated and wellformed.

i tried creating different documents of xml and dtd, but i get the same error no matter what i do or how simple i make the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "mmm.dtd">
<root>
<name>name_nameson</name>
</root>


<!ELEMENT root (name)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine as long as you have the XML and the DTD on the same file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root [
<!ELEMENT root (name)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
]>

<root>
<name>name_nameson</name>
</root>
```

On separate files this should be your DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT root (name)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
```

and this your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "mmm.dtd">

<root>
<name>name_nameson</name>
</root>
```

Comment: so if i have an external dtd file, it wont validate alone ?

Comment: The external DTD file validates through the XML file so no, the DTD wont validate alone (If I understood the question correctly). To trigger the DTD validation you simply have to validate the XML making sure that you wrote the line that references to the DTD file which is `<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "mmm.dtd">` :)